# Keep line break when getting file to be one word per line?

Tags: sed, text-files, newline

I have a file as such, `infile.txt`:

```
foo bar
hello world
blah blah black sheep
```

I want to get:

```
foo
bar

hello
wolrd

blah 
blah 
black 
sheep
```

I've tried this

```
echo infile.txt | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' | grep -v '^$'
```

but it doesn't recognize the line breaks and outputs:

```
foo
bar
hello
wolrd
blah 
blah 
black 
sheep
```

**How do I achieve the desired output?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `sed` version: (does not give new line at end)

```
sed '$!G;s/ /\n/g' file
foo
bar

hello
world

blah
blah
black
sheep
```

The `G` adds new line to the pattern space, and copies the hold space after the new line.
But since hold space is empty, it only adds new line. The  `$!` prevents it run on last line.
`s/ /\n/g` replace all space with new line.

---

Another `sed` version: (does not give new line at end)
(Based on `NeronLeVelu` post)

```
sed '$!s/$/\n/g;s/ /\n/g' file
foo
bar

hello
world

blah
blah
black
sheep
```

How it works:
`$!` not do this on last line -> `s/$/\n/g` replace end of line `$` with `\n` so you get two new line.
`s/ /\n/g` replace all space with newline.

Comment: well done to use the original internal buffer for the new line +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is an  `awk`

```
awk -v OFS="\n" -v ORS="\n\n" '{$1=$1}1' file
foo
bar

hello
world

blah
blah
black
sheep
```

You may also use:

```
awk '$1=$1' OFS="\n" ORS="\n\n" file
```

But this is more robust

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\n" ORS="\n\n" file
```

---

Another version:

```
awk '{gsub(/($| )/,"\n")}1' file
```

---

PS, all `awk` above adds a newline at the end.

This does not add new line at the end if that is a problem:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print a"\n"} {gsub(/ /,"\n");a=$0} END {print a}' file
foo
bar

hello
world

blah
blah
black
sheep
```

Comment: +1. It could also be done with `awk '{gsub(/( |$)/,RS)}1' file` or `sed -r 's/( |$)/\n/g' file` but IMHO `awk -v OFS="\n" -v ORS="\n\n" '{$1=$1}1' file` is the right way to do it clearly and explicitly implements exactly what's required (i.e. change the space field separator to a newline and change the newline output record separator to 2 newlines) and it's easily extended.

Comment: @EdMorton Updated my post.  PS the `sed` give one blank line at end, so it may be written: `sed '$!s/$/\n/g;s/ /\n/g'`

Comment: The awk one will give a blank line at the end too but I figure that's fine since every other group of lines in the file is succeeded by a blank line too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below sed command,

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\n\n/g;s/ /\n/g' file
foo
bar

hello
world

blah
blah
black
sheep
```

- Single new line characters are replaced by  double new line characters.
- Again spaces are replaced by a new line character.

Comment: Can you also explain the `:a;N;$!ba` part of your `sed`.

Comment: explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n). I think you must know about this...

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '$ !s/$/\
/;s/ /\
/g' YourFile
```

1. add a new line at the end of each line but last
2. replace space by new line

Comment: Post your output.  I do get three lines from this like `foo^Jbar^J` and `hello^Jworld^J` etc.

Comment: sorry `^J` is a new line char (copy paste loose this). I adapt the reply